# Using Intstream to generate infinite Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, int, fibonacci

Im having a little issue figuring out how to use stream to generate an infinite sized, sequential stream which contains all the numbers in a fibonacci sequence.

How would I be able to print out an infinite stream? Any advice helps, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream stream = IntStream.generate(new FibonacciSupplier());
        stream.limit(20).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static class FibonacciSupplier implements IntSupplier {

        int current = 1;
        int previous = 0;

        @Override
        public int getAsInt() {
            int result = current;
            current = previous + current;
            previous = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that this stream can't be infinite as soon as you reach the 47th element, the value is too large to fit into a positive integer.

Comment: If I did, you wouldn't have an infinite stream as you asked. you would just have a stream of 7 values.

Answer (score 7):

You might be thinking there's a way of using a `map` operation to generate the sequence. There isn't: Java non-terminal operations are, by design, only able to operate on one element at a time. This allows them to be converted to parallel streams with deterministic results.

Your best option is to generate an infinite stream. Here are a couple of ways of doing that:

```
class Fib {
    private int previous = 0;
    private int current = 1;

    private int next() {
        int temp = previous + current;
        previous = current;
        current = temp;
        return current;
    }

    public IntStream stream() {
        return IntStream.generate(this::next);
    }
}
```

used as `new Fib().stream()`.

You can do this just using arrays as well:

```
IntStream fibStream = Stream.iterate(new int[]{0, 1}, a -> new int[]{a[1], a[0]+a[1]}).mapToInt(a -> a[1])
// print first 20 fibonacci number
fibStream.limit(20).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: .iterable approach is more interesting. This solution comfortable for start F.seq from other point.